# Check data is avalible in Firebase or not in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2LsD.jpg)
in my  flutter project when user login with mobile number ,it check either number is available in fire base ,but i sometime i get this error

Comment: sometime i get message like your account is temporary suspended

Comment: You have to generate SHA keys from your system & add it to Firebase. Without SHA keys, your authentication won't work.